# Binding to systemd device units of connected bluetooth devices

Tags: linux, systemd, udev, bluetooth, bluez

When I connect a bluetooth device (e.g. a wiimote) to my machine and list all device units of systemd via `systemctl list-units -t device`, the device unit shows up as `sys-subsystem-bluetooth-devices-hci0:ID.device`.

## Problem:

I want to bind a systemd service to a specific bluetooth device unit (e.g. wiimote). Thus, I will need an idea about the name. The **ID** differs on two Arch linux machines.

## Questions:

- Who assigns these device **ID**s to bluetooth systemd device units?
- Is the **ID** static on **one** system and among system updates and thus is it safe binding services to that device unit, i.e., will this service only be triggered when connecting a bluetooth device of the same type?
- Can I change/influence this **ID**?

---

## Attempts:

I tried to change the **ID** with an udev rule following this [description on the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php). Via `udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/hidraw4 )` I got:

```
looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:057E:0330.000C/hidraw/hidraw4':
KERNEL=="hidraw4"
SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw"
DRIVER==""

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:057E:0330.000C':
KERNELS=="0005:057E:0330.000C"
SUBSYSTEMS=="hid"
DRIVERS=="wiimote"
ATTRS{country}=="00"
ATTRS{devtype}=="gen20"
ATTRS{extension}=="none"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256':
KERNELS=="hci0:256"
SUBSYSTEMS=="bluetooth"
DRIVERS==""
```

All `KERNEL(S)` entries are not the same over two systems. I thus tried to apply the udev rule:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="hid", DRIVERS=="wiimote", TAG+="systemd", SYMLINK+="wii"
```

But that doesn't create any additional device unit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add:

```
ENV{SYSTEMD_ALIAS}="/dev/wii"
```

(which is what `SYMLINK+="wii"` creates) to your udev rule.

After path normalisation, this results in `dev-wii.device`.

(NB: this sounds so simple, but it took me some hours to arrive at, so I'm by no means dismissing it as an easy question! I struggled with it for my own purposes, coming across your question hoping for a solution for myself.)

Tangentially, if your udev rule is split over multiple lines, the breaks escaped with `\`, you also need to ensure that the file ends with an empty line. Otherwise, it appears to be parsed by udev (it's not like the `EOF` character is somehow escaped) but doesn't achieve the desired result.